# Firefox red flash when no search is found

Tags: linux, firefox

I see a very big and annoying red flash in the whole browser when I search and nothing is found. Is totally unexpected, and I don't understand why happens in an older browser too.

This is the third time that I try to post this question.
I decided to record my screen to show the problem.

The video shows the same problem in both Firefox browsers, in different computers.

Modern Firefox version (this): 103.0 (64-bit).

VPS older version: 78.15.0esr (64-bit), never changed a setting.

Same thing.

[image]

Anyone knows why is happening this?

Tried private mode (see video), no plugins.

Tried stupid things like change wayland/xorg.

Tried default and other themes.

I could understand that my regular Firefox behaves different, what I can't really understand is why a vanilla Firefox in Debian does the same thing.

And yes, it's totally unexpected and eye hurting.

Tried a new profile, no changes.
Tried clean startup (no plugins), no changes.

Comment: Are you using any plugins?

Comment: question updated

Comment: Try clearing the startup cache

Comment: try default => about:profiles

Comment: VPS old Firefox is default. Tried a new profile in my regular computer but didn't make a difference.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a feature of your DE. Do you have any accessibility features enabled? Have you checked if it happens with default DE config?

Comment: Made your comment an answer, I will vote you. Accesibility seems enabled by default in both my KDE and seems also in the VPS xfce. The setting is called: Visual ring. Thank you. Nevermind it's activated by default in both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a feature of Firefox. It looks more like a feature of your Desktop Environment that enhances Firefox's alert sound and small red flash in the search box. Check if you have any accessibility settings enabled in DE's settings.

Comment: In KDE, the accesibility setting is called "Visual ring". Thank you!